# How to encrypt connections to SQL Server in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

What encryption is best for me to use to encrypt the SQL Server client to node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Try below Link to encrypt SQL Server connections

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.